# URL filtering and posting to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save a URL like the one below in a MySQL table

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+rel+scape&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=uUt&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&sa=X&ei=t_jMTtvUE4jfsgbA_4HdDA&ved=0CBgQvwUoAQ&q=mysql+real+escape&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=6f9f60a823dcbbc2&biw=1920&bih=901
```

but it's only saved up to

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=mysql rel scape
```

I tried UTF-8, text, varchar column types but it doesn't seem to work. This is what i use for my insert query:

```
'".addslashes($_POST['url'])."',
```

Can anyone point me out where is the problem?

Comment: Interesting that is only goes up to the first "&" character... or maybe it means nothing

Comment: Please switch to using parameterized queries. `addslashes` and even `mysql_real_escape_string` will not prevent SQL injection attacks. See my answer to this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165500/efficiently-sanitize-user-entered-text/8169705#8169705

Comment: Also, please post your full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the full url, you will have to use urlencode

```
$url = urlencode('http://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+rel+scape&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=uUt&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&sa=X&ei=t_jMTtvUE4jfsgbA_4HdDA&ved=0CBgQvwUoAQ&q=mysql+real+escape&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=6f9f60a823dcbbc2&biw=1920&bih=901');
```

This will store the `&` as `&amp;` which can be stored in the database.

Don't forget to take a look at security, never accept a $_POST blindly in your database. Like Polynomial said: [Efficiently sanitize user entered text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165500/efficiently-sanitize-user-entered-text/8169705#8169705)

Comment: well this kinda helped. im still checking for more solutions. thank you so much