# Array_Map on $_POST variables from a multiple select list

Tags: php

I am trying to run an array_map (two, technically) on all values received from a $_POST variable, from a multiple select list.

Here's the code:

```
$culture = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_map('html2txt', $_POST['culture[]']));
```

Should this work?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape database values. It is not a secure solution. Instead, use parameterized queries. See my answer to this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165500/efficiently-sanitize-user-entered-text/8169705#8169705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code looks perfectly fine to me. That's the way to do consecutive array_map's.

Comment: Addendum: That looks fine to me, *except the glaring security issues*.